# How do I delete my town and player on Animal Crossing New Leaf

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In my game of Animal Crossing New Leaf I can not delete my town and player because (I think) its old. **I don't have Isabelle in my game** and some buildings that you are supposed have at the start of the game. I started in a taxi not in a train with Rover. I have done a lot of research on this and haven't seen anything like it. Pelly at the town hall tells me how to but I have to take out my game card but I don't know how to do that and I don't understand it. Does any know what's going on? Does anyone know how to delete my world? Anything would be helpful. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's sounds like you've gotten lost and are currently playing Animal Crossing: Wild World. This was released for DS some time ago, and is the only Animal Crossing game to involve a taxi...

It's a lot of fun, but is definitely a different game than New Leaf. If you can confirm that you are in fact playing New Leaf with a taxi I'd love to see some screen shots, though I'd take a look at the start screen to verify.

Your should be able to delete your town from the start menu as well, by going to "Other Things" and then choosing "Rebuild Town".

Answer (score -1):

Sorry if you want Animal Crossing New Leaf but thats Animal Crossing Wild World. To delete everything I would redo the question but say this is wild world. Im sure some people that play Wild World can help you.